# Is it possible to quick-access apps on iOS 10 without unlocking?

Tags: ios

I'm searching if it is possible to quick access apps other than Apple's on the lock-screen widget without unlocking the phone. Currently I can't find enough information, but based on what I know and found, I think it's a no. So I'm looking for an alternative. Would not putting a lock code on the phone suffice?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that un-securing the entire phone to provide easy access to one app is not going to be the way to do it. What makes you think that your app ought to have priority over any other anyway? Users put apps on their springboard in order of their own priority.

Comment: @Tetsujin it's not for a general-purpose phone and not a general purpose app (enterprise-ish environment), so un-securing would be an option if there's no other way. I also removed parts about development, so the question could be a general topic. I just want to know if there's a way to quick-access an app without needing to unlock the phone. A good example would be the swipe to left to access the Camera app, something like that.